# distinct value row from the table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table with values as below,

```
Id  Value 
1   1   
2   1
3   2
4   2
5   3
6   4
7   4
```

now need to write a query to retrieve value from the table and output should look as

```
ID Value
1   1
3   2
5   3
6   4
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: how is this distinct ?

Comment: So you need the `MIN(Id)` for each `Value`? Then that is exactly that you need to code.

Comment: I suggest you to read about [aggregate functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and try *something* by yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you want is nothing to do with being *distinct*, it's a simple aggregation of `value` with the minimum `ID` for each:

```
select Min(id) Id, value
from table
group by value
```